# SQL Request and Display

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display database entries on a page in an unordered list. I'm echoing my rows in my li's, my sql connection seems fine... I don't understand where I went wrong... Does anyone have an idea?

```
<body class="projects">

    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "project");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM companies";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    ?>

    <div id="projects" class="container">

        <h1>Projects</h1>

        <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_row());
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <?php
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I dont know if this is the principal issue in your code but I dont see your `endwhile` http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: The content is simply not being displayed. The number of lis varies according to the number of rows though..

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ul>        
    <?php
    while($row = $mysqli->fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<li>
            <h2>".$row['name']."</h2>
            <p>".$row['description']."</p>
        </li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Or you can wrap the echo with {$row['item']} instead of what I did above with going in and out of HTML.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work neither... I've tried adding endwhile at the end and printf instead of echo but I can't get it to work. Any more suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: What does it look like when you var dump inside the while loop of $row?

Comment: It displays the db content however it displays code like array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(16)

Comment: Updated with a new piece